# I want to export an object from index.js to exam.js

Tags: javascript, html

Both the scripts files index.js and exam.js are linked respectively to index.html and exam.html.
but styling in index.js is causing this error

> (index.js:193 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'style')
> at index.js:193:37 (anonymous) @ index.js:193)*

in the exam.js file

**index.js file setup**

```
document.querySelector('.container').style.backgroundColor = 'green'
export const colors = {red: 'red', blue: 'blue'}
```

**exam.js file setup**

```
import {colors} from './index.js'
console.log(colors);
```

note both script tags have the type attribute (modules) in their respective html file. How do I stop the `document.querySelector('.container').style.backgroundColor = 'green'` from giving me the above error, because without the above styling the code exports perfectly?

Comment: Well `document.querySelector('.container')` seems to be returning `null`, are you sure it exists in "index.html"?

Comment: Also make sure to load the script after the HTML body elements (especially the one with class `container`), not before them.

Comment: yes the document.querySelector('.container') is in the index.html file

Comment: and the script tag is at the end of the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that '.container' exists in the DOM when the script is executed?
Just try something like this:

```
export const colors = ...your object...;

const targetEl = document.querySelector('.container');

if(!targetEl) {
  return;
}
targetEl.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```